# Login with Hash md5(md5)

Tags: php, md5, bcrypt

i'm a newbie. Now, i have a problem with 2 database user login. I have a DB1 and passwords hash md5(md5) . DB2 is OJS (open journal system). I want to use acount of DB1 to login to OJS. I know, when i login on OJS, system will hash the input string from validation form and compare with DB. I want change the type hash to sample DB1 md5(md5).

```
function verifyPassword($username, $password, $hash, &$rehash) {
    if (password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)) {
        // update to new hashing algorithm
        $oldHash = Validation::encryptCredentials($username, $password, false, true);

        if ($oldHash === $hash) {
            // update hash
            $rehash = Validation::encryptCredentials($username, $password);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return password_verify($password, $hash);
}
```

DB1 hash

```
md5(md5($pass))
```

Comment: Why do you want to switch to the weak `md5(md5(...));` hash?

Comment: BCRYPT creates a secure password verifier, MD5 does not nor does md5(md5). When using PHP just use `password_hash` and `1password_verify`, that is a secure solution.

Comment: Because i use a system 6 year ago, and i don't know the deverloper of this choose the hasf md5(md5)). Now, i building a new system Open Journal System (OJS) and i want to use account of the old system to login OJS.